# Proven Algorithm for breaking data into batches of same size

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I need to club following sorted data into batch of same size, let say `100k`.

```
181000 : Zee5
164000 : VootSelect
40000 : SunNxt
30000 : SonyLiv
21213 : Prime
13505 : VootKids
10616 : epicOn
4705 : ErosNow
2438 : Hungama
1878 : CuriosityStream
849 : Tatasky
116 : docubay
50 : Shemaroome
```

Expected:

> Batch 1: 100000 : Zee5
>
> Batch 2: 81000 : Zee5 19000 : VootSelect
>
> Batch 3: 100000 : VootSelect
>
> Batch 4: 45000 : VootSelect 40000 : SunNxt 15000 : SonyLiv
>
> Batch 5: So on....

I tried to build my own logic for same, using the following greedy algorithm found on [hackerearth](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/greedy/basics-of-greedy-algorithms/tutorial/):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
const int MAX = 105;
int A[MAX];

int main()
{
    int T, N, numberOfThings = 0, currentTime = 0;
    cin >> N >> T;
    for(int i = 0;i < N;++i)
        cin >> A[i];
    sort(A, A + N);
    for(int i = 0;i < N;++i)
    {
        currentTime += A[i];
        if(currentTime > T)
            break;
        numberOfThings++;
    }
    cout << numberOfThings << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Solution didn't worked,not sure greedy algorithm is best suited for this.**

As this scenario is not very rare, peoples may solve this type of use case often, I am **looking for proven algorithm** to solve this use case.

Comment: It looks like you already have the algorithm to create batches of 100k, why can't you simply use that one?

Comment: *"I tried to build my own logic for same"*: the code you refer to is fine. What is the problem?

Comment: It is not solving the usecase.